# Automata theory on infinite words: any video lectures?

Tags: reference-request, automata, online-resources

I am fun of automata theory (on infinite words). Can you suggest good video lectures on the subject?

An ideal course would cover topics like Buchi automata, LTL->Buchi translation, Streett and parity automata, determinization (or idea...), complementation, minimization, alternating automata. Also touching the topic of tree automata.

I am sure these topics are taught in universities that have strong formal-methods groups (e.g. in Munich, Saarland, Paris, Warsaw, etc.), but, unfortunately, those lectures are neither recorded nor shared (to my knowledge).

(there is a good one [here](http://www.automata.rwth-aachen.de/teaching/videos.en), but it is accessible from RWTH University only)

Comment: You might want to search the internet using the terms "automatic sequences" and "combinatorics on words"

Comment: While it's not a video lecture, Wikipedia's page on infinitary automata (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-automaton ) should provide an excellent starting point with a number of terms to get you searching further and even a pointer to a slide show.

Answer (score 1):

I found this lecture on Theory of Computation on youtube:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyUK5RAJg1c

I also suggest you get the book of Michael Sipser -- Introduction to the Theory of Computation.

Comment: if you have something about automata on _infinite_ words, please share. and thanks for the link(i do have the book, yea, it is very good)!

Answer (score 1):

Try this out on youtube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=KOu6IUssxbs

Please inform me whether that was helpful or not

Comment: The video you suggested is an interesting _beginner_-level source, which is given in the broader context of model checking (it explains what are buchi automata and some simple properties). It is not bad, but what I am looking for is a more in-depth course that covers topics like: buchi automata, LTL->Buchi translation, determinization (or idea...), complementation, minimization, alternating automata, etc. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I try to find something better......